# How can I get my regression model results to be outputted in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

So I am trying to print out the result for my `fit1` model, but I can't seem to resolve why I am getting this error message in my r shiny app: `cannot coerce class ‘c("train", "train.formula")’ to a data.frame`.

Edit: The `train` function is coming from the `caret` package.

**The result I want to get**:

```
  intercept     RMSE  Rsquared      MAE  RMSESD RsquaredSD    MAESD
  1      TRUE 11222.05 0.1019506 8760.358 377.088 0.01622065 168.4909
```

**Sample data**:

```
"","age","sex","bmi","children","smoker","region","expenses"
"1",19,"0",27.9,0,"1","0",16884.92
"2",18,"1",33.8,1,"0","1",1725.55
"3",28,"1",33,3,"0","1",4449.46
"4",33,"1",22.7,0,"0","2",21984.47
"5",32,"1",28.9,0,"0","2",3866.86
"6",31,"0",25.7,0,"0","1",3756.62
"7",46,"0",33.4,1,"0","1",8240.59
"8",37,"0",27.7,3,"0","2",7281.51
"9",37,"1",29.8,2,"0","3",6406.41
"10",60,"0",25.8,0,"0","2",28923.14
"11",25,"1",26.2,0,"0","3",2721.32
"12",62,"0",26.3,0,"1","1",27808.73
```

**ui**:

```
source(global.R)
sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("proportion", "Proportion of data you want to use: ",
                              min = 0.1, max = 0.9, value = 0.5, step = 0.1),
      checkboxInput("mlrmodel","Check if you want to display the multiple linear regression model: "),
      conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.mlrmodel == 1",
         checkboxInput("ageid", "Age"),
         checkboxInput("sexid", "Sex"),
                  )
      ),
      mainPanel(
                  box(tableOutput("mlrmodelplot"))
                )
              )
```

**server**:

```
 source(global.R)
 getData <- reactive({
 newData <- insurance_data_update #%>% filter(sex == input$sex)#, smoker==input$smoker, region==input$region)
 })
 
 
 trainsplit <- reactive({
 set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
 train = sample(1:nrow(getData()), size=nrow(getData())*input$proportion)
 })
 traindata <- reactive({
 train_data = getData()[trainsplit(), ]
 })
 testpilot <- reactive({
 test = dplyr::setdiff(1:nrow(getData()), trainsplit())
 })
 testdata <- reactive({
 test_data = getData()[testpilot(), ]
 })

 output$mlrmodelplot = renderTable({
 if(input$mlrmodel){
    if(input$ageid){
       fit1 <- train(expenses ~ age, data = traindata(),
                  method = "lm", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5))
       fit1
    }
  }
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does this `train` function come from? What does it return? What ever it is doesn't seem to be a data.frame. Maybe try `broom::tidy(fit1)` to see if it's supported by the broom package to turn it into a data.frame for you. Otherwise please make sure the example is complete enough so we can copy/paste it into R to run it ourselves to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, the `train` function is coming from the `caret` package.

Comment: Actually given your desired output, maybe `broom::glance(fit1)` might be a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use `fit$results.`  The output from train() is a list, so you need to select the attribute you want, which in your case is the "results" attribute.  Try updating your server function like this:

```
source(global.R)
 getData <- reactive({
 newData <- insurance_data_update #%>% filter(sex == input$sex)#, smoker==input$smoker, region==input$region)
 })
 
 
 trainsplit <- reactive({
 set.seed(123) # For reproducibility
 train = sample(1:nrow(getData()), size=nrow(getData())*input$proportion)
 })
 traindata <- reactive({
 train_data = getData()[trainsplit(), ]
 })
 testpilot <- reactive({
 test = dplyr::setdiff(1:nrow(getData()), trainsplit())
 })
 testdata <- reactive({
 test_data = getData()[testpilot(), ]
 })

 output$mlrmodelplot = renderTable({
 if(input$mlrmodel){
    if(input$ageid){
       fit1 <- train(expenses ~ age, data = traindata(),
                  method = "lm", preProcess = c("center", "scale"), trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5))
       fit1$results
    }
  }
})
```